# How to use html2pdf to print html pages

Tags: php, html2pdf

I am using `html2pdf` library in order to generate pdf from html file.

I don't know how to check out width arrangements.

I had this library from source forge. If anyone has idea about it or manual about `html2pdf`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think what you are asking is how to change the page width of the outputted PDF file.  The answer is to change the width in the settings before you call AddPage().  [Here](http://www.dancrintea.ro/html-to-pdf/) is an example of how to do so:
[Here](http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/addpage.htm) are the settings you will need:
Basically, it would look something like this:

```
require("html2fpdf.php"); 
$htmlFile = "http://www.cnn.com"; 
$buffer = file_get_contents($htmlFile); 

$pdf = new HTML2FPDF('P', 'mm', 'Legal'); 
$pdf->AddPage(); 
$pdf->WriteHTML($buffer); 
$pdf->Output('my.pdf', 'F');
```

This, if I am getting the code right, would output a PDF called my.pdf that is formatted as a legal-size page in portrait mode.